# How to fix flexbox expandable menu's bugs in Firefox and Chromium?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, flexbox

I have hideable sidebar with nav menu. Everything's use flexbox and everything's alright except expandable menu (second from above). Menu crop in the beginning in Firefox and crossing with social icons in Chromium? How to fix this? I use PostCSS's cssnext and cssfixes.

Full code: https://codepen.io/arch2/pen/dNgKxq

```
<input type="checkbox" class="sidebar-checkbox" id="sidebar-checkbox" />
<div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation__list">
      <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./index.html" title="ГЛАВНАЯ">ГЛАВНАЯ</a></li>
      <li class="navigation_item dropdown__toggle"><a href="./lyrics.html" title="ТЕКСТЫ">ТЕКСТЫ</a>
        <ul class="navigation__list dropdown">
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#***" title="***">***</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#SagaORonine" title="SagaORonine">САГА О РОНИНЕ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#malo" title="malo">МАЛО</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#kluvikiNot" title="kluvikiNot">КЛЮВИКИ НОТ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#vKluvikah" title="vKluvikah">В КЛЮВИКАХ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#krasnayaPesnya" title="krasnayaPesnya">КРАСНАЯ ПЕСНЯ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#les" title="les">ЛЕС</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#chernoknizhnica" title="chernoknizhnica">ЧЕРНОКНИЖНИЦА</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#terem" title="terem">ТЕРЕМ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#gerbarij" title="gerbarij">ГЕРБАРИЙ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#vnutriGerbariya" title="vnutriGerbariya">ВНУТРИ ГЕРБАРИЯ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#teploBezdonnoe" title="teploBezdonnoe">ТЕПЛО БЕЗДОННОЕ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#malchikBatiskaf" title="malchikBatiskaf">МАЛЬЧИК-БАТИСКАФ</a></li>
          <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./lyrics.html#igrushki" title="igrushki">ИГРУШКИ</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation_item"><a href="./about.html" title="О ГРУППЕ">О ГРУППЕ</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <address class="soc-link">
    <a class="soc-link__item" href="https://vk.com/caddysmelledliketrees" title="https://vk.com/caddysmelledliketrees">
      <i class="fa fa-vk" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="soc-link__item" href="https://youtube.com/channel/UCDUU-xPtMQ2VOpYaMv-OvLw" title="https://youtube.com/channel/UCDUU-xPtMQ2VOpYaMv-OvLw">
      <i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="soc-link__item" href="https://instagram.com/caddysmellslike" title="https://instagram.com/caddysmellslike">
      <i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="soc-link__item" href="http://last.fm/ru/music/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8" title="http://last.fm/ru/music/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82+%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8">
      <i class="fa fa-lastfm" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="soc-link__item" href="https://soundcloud.com/caddysmelledliketrees" title="https://soundcloud.com/caddysmelledliketrees">
      <i class="fa fa-soundcloud" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="soc-link__item" href="https://caddysmelledliketrees.bandcamp.com" title="https://caddysmelledliketrees.bandcamp.com">
      <i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
    <a class="soc-link__item" href="mailto:info@caddysmellsliketrees.ru?subject=Общие%20вопросы"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  </address>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.navigation` and `.soc-link` should not be `display: flex;` you want these two to be normal block elements. The flex is causing them to overlap because they aren't respecting their children's sizes.